# Time between specified range

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, time

I have a cron job running on Rails server. This rake task make calls/SMS to subscribers when some event triggers. Now when this event trigger between 10 PM to 8 AM I want to store it in a queue as no one likes to get disturbed in the middle of the night. How do I check if the time is between 10 PM - 8 AM window.

Note: Every user has its own timezone.. Which I have in the database

Thanks

Comment: Currently I'm checking this using an array containing all hours in between. ie

`hour_array = %w(22 23 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)`

`store_in_queue if hour_array.include?(Time.now.utc.hour.to_s)`

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like ...

```
def night_time?(t)
  t.hour > 22 || t.hour < 8
end
```

Could be used:

```
store_in(queue) if not night_time?(@time)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
# here "-07:00" is example of user's timezone offset 
if Time.now.getlocal("-07:00").hour.between?(8, 22) 
  #then we send
else
  #we don't send
end
```