# How to implement Do Not Disturb (DND) with User selection for Start Time, TimeZOne, End Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time, drag-and-drop

I have a cron job running on Rails server. This rake task make calls/SMS to subscribers when some event triggers. Now when this event trigger between User selected DND Time I want to store it in a queue. How do I check if the time is between DND time selected by user.

I tried answer mention in [Time between specified range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738781/time-between-specified-range)

But it fails when user select DND Time as 6 to 9

```
Note:- 1] Every user has its own timezone.. Which I have in the database
2] Every user can select his/her own DND Time.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think following will work
If

```
start_hour = Hour when DND Time Starts
end_hour = Hour when DND Time Ends
current hour = Hour of the current time
```

Then

```
if start_hour > end_hour
  current hour > start_hour || current hour < end_hour
else
  current hour > start_hour && current hour < end_hour
end
```

OR

```
start_hour > end_hour ?  (current hour > start_hour || current hour < end_hour) : 
                         (current hour > start_hour && current hour < end_hour)
```